# How to 'unescape' a string that is appearing different from the file it comes from?

Tags: c#

I have html stored in a file

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"\n  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">
```

I'm reading it in with the following:

```
        string existingHtml;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("file.txt")))
        {
            existingHtml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

When I inspect `existingHtml`, it contains the following, with all the characters escaped:

```
"\"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\\\"\\n  \\\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\\\">
```

How can I 'unescape' `existingHtml` so that it contains the exact same string as what's stored in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape anything

Viewing strings whilst paused in the debugger can be misleading since it escapes slashes.

Print it to a console window or `Response.Write` it, it will be fine.

Comment: Its worth noting that what you see in the debugger is exactly the same as you would write if you said "existingHtml = [debugstring]". This is why it is surrounded in quotes and thus needs the escaping to be done.